# Select items and set an unmapped property with linq to SQL

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, linq

Consider the following POCO's in my Database:

```
public class Person
{
    [Key]
    public Int32 PersonId { get; set; }

    public String Name { get; set; }

    public Collection<Pet> Pets { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public Int32 NumberOfPets { get; set; }
}

public class Pet
{
    [Key]
    public Int32 PetId { get; set; }

    public Int32 PersonId { get; set; }

    public Person Person { get; set; }

    public String Name { get; set; }
}
```

I would like the `NumberOfPets` property set when I fetch People from my repository, but I do not want to implicitly Join Pets all the time.

```
public class PersonRepository
{
    public IList<Person> GetAllPeople1()
    {
        return _context.People.Select(x => { x.NumberOfPets = x.Pets.Count(); return x; } ).ToList();
    }
    public IList<Person> GetAllPeople2()
    {
        return _context.People.Select(x => new Person
        {
            NumberOfPets = x.Pets.Count(),
            Name = x.Name
        }).ToList();
    }
    public IList<Person> GetAllPeople3()
    {
        var people = _context.People;
        foreach (var p in people)
        {
            p.NumberOfPets = p.Pets.Count();
        }
        return people.ToList();
    }
}
```

Method 1 works, but not with Linq to SQL. #2 works but is error prone as more properties are added to Person, it would be easy to forget to add it here. #3 is going to generate a whole bunch of queries. I know how to accomplish this using purse SQL, but not sure how to make EF do the work for me in an efficient manner.

Is there a syntax that will make #1 work while generating a (semi) efficient query?

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe there's any better way than #2 (but as you mentioned, has problems of its own).

Some alternatives:

1. Write a view which represents the data you're after. Query against the view instead of directly against `Person`.
2. Leverage lazy loading. Implement `NumberOfPets` as:

```
public int NumberOfPets { get { return Pets.Count(); } }
```

Here, `NumberOfPets` will only query the pets table *when* accessed. You could also bake in some caching, if you'd like.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation. I ToList() right away, so N queries of 'select count(*) from Pets were PetId = xx' would be generated, every time...